# Cloning a git repo with a shell script - Shell adds a space after ".git"?

Tags: git, shell

I'm trying to do a very simple task, which is cloning a git repo and cd into it.

I have this shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Clone a git repository, and go into it
git clone git@someNumbers:myGitRepo.git
cd myGitRepo
```

When I run this, shell thinks there the git repo is "clone git@someNumbers:myGitRepo.git " (WITH A SPACE, THERE IS NO SPACE IN MY CODE, I'M SURE)!

and outputs:

```
Cloning into 'myGitRepo.git '...
```

when it should say:

```
Cloning into 'myGitRepo'...
```

I've also tried to copy paste both commands (in one go) to the Command prompt, but also then, it will fail in the same way. Only by running it alone, or copypasting it without an linebrake in the end, will successfully clone the git repo.

What is going on here? How can I write a simple shell script that can clone a git repository?

Comment: Is that an actual copy/paste of your script? I suspect there's some Unicode space-like character at the end that is not showing up here. Inspect the output of `od -tx1c myscript.sh` to make sure.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102008/how-do-i-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-from-each-line-of-some-output

Comment: Does this happen on Windows ? Check that the editor you are using to edit your script saves your files with Uniw line endings (`LF`) and not Windows line endings (`CR LF`)

Comment: @Thomas I did what you said and there is indeed some characters there, here's what it outputs: ```. g   i   t 342 200 213  \n   c   d```

Comment: So is it bad or good @Thomas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you wrote that `od -tx1c myscript.sh` shows `. g   i   t 342 200 213  \n   c   d`. That's UTF-8 encoding for [U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE](http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/200B.html), which – apparently – is not recognized as whitespace by the shell.

If you can't see it in your editor, just remove the entire line including the newline at the end, and type it in from scratch.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem as I copied some of the code I used from one place. Must be why I had those weird characters.